# What's the best way to automate file renaming?

Tags: file, automation, file-rename

Here's the situation:

I have an excel file which contains the following information:
Document location: (C:/folder/sub/file.doc)
and Document New Name: (RENAMED-FILE.doc)

What would be the be the best way to automate this as I have about a thousand files to rename?

*Note:
Document location can be in different locations (files will not always be inside folder/sub)
Document new name has no naming convention.

So basically, everything has to come from the excel file, or I have to change the excel file into something (maybe a CSV file?) to have it work with another utility.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting it to CSV or another easily parse-able text format and then writing a quick script to rename things would probably be the fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question with a well-versed google search:

http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/rename-multiple-files-bulk-excel-googl-docs/2481/

Thank you for your time though Dav :)